# PHP Search array recursively and return count of index 'x'?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that lets you search an array recursively and return the number of instances a certain key 'x' occurs (regardless of how deep)?

Answer (score 5):

Now yes. :)

```
function count_key($array, $key) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $val) {
        if($k == $key)
            $count++;
        if(is_array($val))
        $count += count_key($val, $key);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is pretty much what the [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function is for, but</strike> if you're using a multi-dimensional array as you imply, if would be fairly trivial to put something together using the [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function.

Comment: But this counts values not keys.

Comment: I mean in theory you could use it together with `array_keys` but as every key only occurs one time... ;-D

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

```
function recursiveSum($array, $keyToSearch) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $total += recursiveSum($value, $keyToSearch);
        }
        else if($key == $keyToSearch) {
            $total += $value;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

$total = recursiveSum($array, "test");
```

Comment: Not totally correct, `else if` should be only `if`. Otherwise `$foo[$key] = array()` would not be taken into account.

Comment: @Felix yeah thats corect my bad :

Comment: @Felix to return the summ of the array items like $a = array("test" =>1,array("test"=>2));
$total = recursiveSum($array, "test");
would return 3

Comment: Yes but the OP asked for a function that **counts** the number of **occurrences** of a certain key, not the sum of the values of that key.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. Write your own! Recursion is fun! =D